# How to display records from tables linked by a foreign key?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables called: subjects, students and entries.

The subjects table has the fields: subject_id, subject_name and exam_board.

The students table has the fields: student_id, name.

The entries table has 2 foreign keys linked to subject_id and student_id which are both primary keys of the above tables.

They have various records.
How do I display the names of students with a certain exam board?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id, name
FROM students t1
INNER JOIN entries t2
    ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id
INNER JOIN subjects t3
    ON t2.subject_id = t3.subject_id
WHERE t3.exam_board = 'some board'
```

I used `DISTINCT student_id, name` to cover the possibility that a given student may have taken the same board more than once, across multiple subjects.